# Error: [$parse:syntax] while passing a method definition as String

Tags: angularjs

I'm working on a project using AngularJS. What I'm trying to do is to write my method's definition on my controller and pass it as string to be execute on a click even in client side:

And here is an example of what I'm trying to do:

My controller:

```
$scope.myMethod = "add({'a':3,'b':4})";
add (o)
{
 return o.a+o.b; 
}
```

My HTML page:

```
<button ng-click={{ myMethod }} ></button>
```

But I keep getting the Error: [$parse:syntax].

Can you tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The binding will insert the whole string:

```
"content"
```

That is to say, it inserts " inline, and since attribute values are enclosed by " as well, the inserted " ends the value expression prematurely. The rendered HTML looks like this:

```
ng-click=""add({'a':3,'b':4})""
```

Guard the binding with ', like this:

```
ng-click="'{{myMethod}}'"
```

I don't agree with the way you're inserting a method into the HTML, nor am I sure it works, but the above will fix the $parse error.